# X509Certificate2.import can not find file under current folder

Tags: x509certificate2

```
$localPfx = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$localPfx.Import(".\myCert.pfx", "password", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
```

I got

```
Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I use

```
$PfxFileFull = Convert-Path .\myCert.pfx
```

or

```
$PfxFileFull = "D:\...\myCert.pfx" #full path
```

Then run

```
$localPfx.Import($PfxFileFull, "password", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
```

Then the exception goes away.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Trust the system. For Some reason it can’t find the file. Ensure everything is set correctly, that’s how systems work.

Try copying it to C:/

Try using forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Are you executing as admin?

Comment: The relative path could be anywhere depending on how you run the script. Test-Path +resolve-path might be worth adding.